# What use is a Star Piece?

Tags: pokemon-go

With the recent update, a new item was introduced in Pokemon Go: Star Piece. In previous Pokemon games this was only to get ingame money and minor other things ([source](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Star_Piece)). Because there is no currency as such in Pokemon Go, what can I do with it?

Answer (score 7):

This new item increases all of your acquired stardust by 50% for 30 minutes per use. So basically what a lucky egg for experience is, a Star Piece is for stardust (but with 50% extra, instead of doubling it).

Comment: Actually, it's a 50% boost, not double.

Answer (score 4):

A Star Piece provides a 50% stardust boost for 30 minutes, similar in function to a Lucky Egg.

For reference, see the [Game Master](https://github.com/BrunnerLivio/pokemongo-game-master) file.